# When check test on Github test raise TimeoutException and FAILED, but in PyCharm PASSED

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests

Good day!
this is my test:

```
def test_check_log_in(driver):
    driver.get('https://openweathermap.org/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.owm-loader-container > div')))
    expected_log = 'Sign in'
    search_option_log = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.user-li a'))).text
    assert expected_log == search_option_log
```

link on Github:
https://github.com/MKeSiMu/OpenWeatherPython_06/blob/develop/tests/test_teachers.py

In PyCharm can Pass this test, but when I push it to Github, test is FAILED:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
______________________________ test_chack_log_in _______________________________

driver = <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="d8fdd763d163e4027e62c7e6a7f568ea")>

    def test_chack_log_in(driver):
        driver.get('https://openweathermap.org/')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.owm-loader-container > div')))
        expected_log = 'Sign in'
>       WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.user-li a'), 'Sign in'))

tests/test_group_qa_ua.py:44: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait (session="d8fdd763d163e4027e62c7e6a7f568ea")>
method = <function text_to_be_present_in_element.<locals>._predicate at 0x7f68d23a6dd0>
message = ''

    def until(self, method, message: str = ""):
        """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the \
        return value does not evaluate to ``False``.
    
        :param method: callable(WebDriver)
        :param message: optional message for :exc:`TimeoutException`
        :returns: the result of the last call to `method`
        :raises: :exc:`selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` if timeout occurs
        """
        screen = None
        stacktrace = None
    
        end_time = time.monotonic() + self._timeout
        while True:
            try:
                value = method(self._driver)
                if value:
                    return value
            except self._ignored_exceptions as exc:
                screen = getattr(exc, "screen", None)
                stacktrace = getattr(exc, "stacktrace", None)
            time.sleep(self._poll)
            if time.monotonic() > end_time:
                break
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py:95: TimeoutException
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED tests/test_group_qa_ua.py::test_chack_log_in - selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
=================== 1 failed, 58 passed in 420.49s (0:07:00) ===================
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I tried to solve this problem by adding time and change some function inside:

```
search_option_log = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.user-li a'))).text

search_option_log = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.user-li a'))).text
```

But still in Github Failed.

Why it is heppening on Github and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found problem. If you visit website first time, the accept cookie window will appear. That is why in header you can not see "Sign in".
Solution is to check if this window is appear and after search needed element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).